# Euler angles - geometry

Tags: rotational-dynamics, coordinate-systems, geometry

[image]

Hello, I don't quite see why should the angle between $\hat{\dot{\theta}}$ and the projection of $\hat{\dot{\phi}}$ onto the $x_0$, $y_0$ plane be a right angle. Does it have something to do with pure geometry or physics? Of course it gives the right answer for the angular velocity as a function of the Euler angles, but I don't see why it is necessarily a right angle.

Comment: What are you asking? Is it "why are coordinate axes orthogonal"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't *have* to be, but convention has it that consecutive rotations in Euler angle schemes be orthogonal to each other.

The orientation is set by a sequence of three rotations, each being perpendicular to the previous rotation such that the influence of one angle to all the other rotations is zero.

And since the sequence $\mathrm{R} = \mathrm{R}_z \mathrm{R}_x \mathrm{R}_y$ consists of three mutually orthogonal rotations, the resulting rotational speed is a sequence of mutually orthogonal relative rotations

$$ \vec{\omega} = \hat{z}_0 \dot{\psi} + \mathrm{R}_z \left( \hat{x}_1 \dot{\theta} + \mathrm{R}_x (\hat{y}_2 \dot{\phi}) \right) $$

In this case, $\hat{z}_0$ is perpendicular to $\mathrm{R}_z \hat{x}_1$, since $\hat{z}_0$ is perpendicular to $\hat{x}_0$ and the rotation $\mathrm{R}_z$ does not change that. Also, $\hat{x}_1$ is perpendicular to $\mathrm{R}_x \hat{y}_2$, since $\hat{x}_1$ is perpendicular to $\hat{y}_1$ and the rotation $\mathrm{R}_x$ does not change that also.